# PHP error log show unable to load dynamic library when uploaded on online host

Tags: php, dynamic-library

On my local host, there is no problem with this project, no warning or an arror, I didn't see error log file to. But, after I uploaded my project to online host, there is error log showing on my root folder. I've googled but not yet found the way to fix it.

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/htscanner.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/htscanner.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Does your host allow you to dynamically load libraries?

Comment: Update your question with what troubleshooting you have already done. For example, does the file exist and are the permissions correct?

Comment: @all, how do i check that my host allow to dynamically load libraries? I'm using codeigniter to built it.
and, yes, the file exist on my root folder. I see that the permissions is 644. Sorry i'm new in web development. Still learn.

Comment: Please provide the whole error, there should be more.

Comment: Does your project include a local `php.ini` or `.user.ini` file? If so, check that for "htscanner". In fact, I would search your entire project for the string "htscanner". It's obvious something is requiring the `htscanner` extension but it does not exist on your server

Comment: I found another problem. My autocomplete not work well. I try my autocomplete on my localhost, work well. But when i upload it, i found console.log say 500 internal server error.  Is this related with error_log on my root folder? I use jQuery ui

Comment: Yes, it's most likely related. The response code from any PHP script with that error will be 500.

Comment: if the problem come from the autocomplete, maybe it caused by ajax, i use ajax to post an keyword to my controller, and then call my model. console.log say `POST http://myweb.com/data/header/lookup 500 (Internal Server Error)`. I've already update my code, enable csrf protection on config.php. Then adding crsf_token_name and csrf_hash at data before sent by ajax. But still `500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: Yes, because of the missing extension error (you know, the one in your question). Focus on that. Have you found any instances of "htscanner" in **any** of your project files?

Comment: @Phil, sorry long to response. This project has work perfectly. But about "htscanner" in error_log still able, i still search about it...

Answer (score 0):

Try add php.ini on your root folder. Then add some default configuration.

Hopely useful